# Coercing previously defined variables using set() from data.table

Tags: r, set, data.table

I was wondering what causes the following behavior that surprised me a bit - I defined a data table `dt_3`, then defined `dt_1` to be equal to `dt_3`. When I then used `set()` to replace row elements in `dt_1`, the corresponding elements of `dt_3` were changed as well:

```
refcols=c("A","B")
dt_3 = data.table(A=c(1,1,3,5,6,7), B = c("x","y","z","q","w","e"), C = rep("NO",6))
dt_2 = data.table(A=c(3,5,7), B = c("z","q","x"), D=c(3,5,99))
dt_1 = dt_3
dt_3
   A B  C
1: 1 x NO
2: 1 y NO
3: 3 z NO
4: 5 q NO
5: 6 w NO
6: 7 e NO

for(j in refcols){
  set(dt_1,2,j,dt_2[3,get(j)])
}
Warning messages:
1: In set(dt_1, 2, j, dt_2[3, get(j)]) :
  Coerced i from numeric to integer. Please pass integer for efficiency; e.g., 2L rather than 2
2: In set(dt_1, 2, j, dt_2[3, get(j)]) :
  Coerced i from numeric to integer. Please pass integer for efficiency; e.g., 2L rather than 2

dt_3
   A B  C
1: 1 x NO
2: 7 x NO
3: 3 z NO
4: 5 q NO
5: 6 w NO
6: 7 e NO
```

What is causing this and is there an easier way to subset by explicit row indices for specific columns like this?

Comment: The warning says exactly what it means. You wrote `2` instead of `2L` in the `i` argument of `set`. Read the warning and read `?set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `copy` so that when we replace the elements in one dataset, the other wont' change

```
dt_1<- copy(dt_3)
```

Regarding the second part, it is not very clear about the row index.  If it is only based on the column index

```
for(j in refcols){
 set(dt_1, i=NULL, j=j, value=dt_2[[j]])
}

dt_1
#   A B  C
#1: 3 z NO
#2: 5 q NO
#3: 7 x NO
#4: 3 z NO
#5: 5 q NO
#6: 7 x NO
```

If the 2nd row of the "A" and "B" column in 'dt_1' should be replaced by the 3rd row of 'dt_2' for corresponding columns (based on 'refcols')

```
for(j in refcols){
 set(dt_1, i=2L, j=j, value=dt_2[[j]][3])
}

dt_1
#   A B  C
#1: 1 x NO
#2: 7 x NO
#3: 3 z NO
#4: 5 q NO
#5: 6 w NO
#6: 7 e NO
```

Comment: The latter interpretation is correct regarding that second part, while your answer to the first part of the question is the main thing that I was looking for (as per question title). Really appreciate it...